# 20px gap between top of ImageView and bottom of status bar after returning from iAd animation

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, iad

I am using IB to place a UIImageView (top) ADBannerView (bottom) and within the same View. When running in the Simulator, if I click on the ad, after dismissing the ad screen, the UIImageView is pushed 20px down, leaving a gap between the status bar and UIImageView.

I've tried playing with all of the AutoResizing settings in the Inspector with no luck. Strangely, other objects, like UITextViews that are superimposed over the UIImageView also shift, but respond to AutoResizing settings such that after setting the struts appropriately, the UITextViews stay in place after returning from the ad animation. ??

This issue seems to be similar to [My view is displaying y=-20 dispite its frame set to y=0. After rotation it snaps back to y=0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032773). However, adding

```
self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

to viewDidLoad is unsuccessful. (I think that's probably because in 3022773 the subview is created programmatically, whereas here its part of the nib)

Also, this post [iAd left white blank screen after closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166977) implies that my parent View (the view holding both UIImageView & ADBannerView) must be a "fullscreen view", but I can't figure out how that applies when using IB. (I don't see ANY settings in Inspector that allow me to tell XCode that the parent View should have that property)

Any ideas out there?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Is your app a full screen app, or do you have the status bar showing? Does your view controller's view property point to the root view, which means that the view's superview is a Window?

Comment: Status bar is showing. I believe that the view controller is pointing to the root view. In my app delegate, applicationDidFinishLaunching method I do:

[window addSubview:[soloViewController view]]; 
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

if that helps...(soloViewController is the view controller and there is only one view, where the ImageView is one subview and the AdBannerView the 2nd subview)